# Check Palindrome Linked List

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, palindrome

I intended to reverse the original LinkedList and compare it with reversed one. If it is identical return true. However, I keep getting the wrong results. Where I did wrong?

```
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) return true;
    
    let reversedHead = reverse(head)
    let count = 0
    while (head != null && reversedHead != null) {
        if(head.val != reversedHead.val) {
            return false
        }
        head = head.next
        reversedHead = reversedHead.next
    }
    if (head == null && reversedHead == null){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
  
};
var reverse =(head)=> {
    let prev = null
    let next = new ListNode()
    let curr = new ListNode()
    curr = head
    while(curr){
        next = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next
    }
    return prev
}
```

Comment: You should create new Nodes in your while loop in the reverse part, not just twice before it. Every node in the reversed list needs to be a new node. And you need to copy over the `val`s. At least you should do all that if your plan of `reverse is to return a new reversed list instead of modifying the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call:

```
let reversedHead = reverse(head)
```

You will have reversed the list, i.e. the head has become the tail, and a tail's next reference is null. Hence your loop will quickly end, as after:

```
head = head.next
```

... `head` will be `null`.

You need to rethink the algorithm. There are several ways to do it...

Instead of an *inplace* reversal, you could let `reverse` return a completely *new* linked list that will have the reversed order:

```
function reverse(head) { // Does not modify the given list. Returns a new one.
    let node = head;
    let reversedHead = null;
    while (node) {
        reversedHead = new ListNode(node.val, reversedHead);
        node = node.next;
    }
    return reversedHead;
}
```

I assume here that the `ListNode` constructor accepts a second argument:

```
class ListNode {
    constructor(val, next=null) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```